# Display maintenance in parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Is there a way to temporarily "disable" all access to a Parse database from an iOS app when performing system maintenance and display a message to user that system is under maintenance using parse?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. If you want such a feature you need to block all public access to your data and use Cloud Functions in your apps. That way you can throw errors during your maintenance and your apps will be able to display a message accordingly.